# About geodesics on a torus

Tags: differential-geometry

Looking at some old midterms online I came across this problem and I'm having some difficulties proving it.

Let $T$ be a torus of revolution paramterized by,
$$x(u,v)=((r\cos u+a)\cos v,(r\cos u+a)\sin v ,r\sin u)$$ where $a,r \in \Bbb{R}$ with $a>r$ and $ 0 < u< 2 \pi$, $0 < v < 2 \pi$.

Prove that if a geodesic is tangent to the parallel $u= \pi/2$, then it is entirely contained in the region of $T$ given by $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le u \le \frac{\pi}{2}$
.

Also show that a geodesic that intersects the parallel $u=0$ under the angle $\theta$ ($0 < \theta < \pi/2$) also intersects the parallel $u=\pi$ if $\cos \theta < \frac{(a-r)}{(a+r)}$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation

Comment: I guess I'm just confused about how to implement this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few types of geodesics on a torus of revolution. There are meridians, which are cirlces going the short way around. There is an inner equator and an outer equator. After those, there are about three types that pass through a point on the outer equator with some starting angle $\theta_0 $ compared with the horizontal.

(A) small $\theta_0,$ in which case Clairaut says that they reach a minimum $r$ away from the $z$ axis, where $\cos \theta = 1$ and $\theta = 0.$ By various symmetry properties, these simply return to the outer equator, and pass through it again at angle $-\theta_0,$ thus making a wave forever

(B) large $\theta_0$ in which they reach the inner equator and pass it at a nonzero angle, in which case they wrap around the torus forever

(C) a critical intermediate value of $\theta_0,$ precisely the one that says that the angle $\theta$ at the inner equator would be $0,$ by Clairaut. In this case, the geodesic never actually reaches the inner equator, it wraps around and around it, getting closer and closer.

do Carmo's first book  does not picture this on the torus. On pages 262-263, he talks about this type (C) for a hyperboloid of revolution, with Figure 4-22.

Comment: +1 Interesting! So just to check that I got it right. The outer equator is sort of stable in the sense that any geodesic close to it and nearly parallel to it will never drift too far away from it. The inner equator OTOH... I can `sorta' see that this is the way it might go, but do need to study this to really understand the details :-)

Comment: Well, your link to Clairaut's relation is a  good start :-)

Comment: @Jyrki, exactly right. If you have a closed geodesic in a region of positive Gauss curvature, other geodesics that cross it will have some tendency to meet it again, as meridians leaving the North Pole of the sphere meet up again at the South Pole. In a region of negative Gauss curvature, geodesics will tend to separate. As far as proving things, you consider some geodesic beginning very near the inner equator with Clairaut's angle $\theta = 0.$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, this was apparently all done by Bliss, the calculus of variations book guy, http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Geodesic_Lines_on_the_Anchor_Ring.html?id=8t5VOQAACAAJ and an article in the Annals http://archive.org/details/jstor-1967147  I looked for pictures of actual anchor rings, I never found any perfect tori of revolution. That's life.

Comment: Alright, a small percentage of these pictures/diagrams have an actual torus rather than the more popular omega shape with a short bar across it. https://www.google.com/search?q=admiralty+anchor+parts&hl=en&client=browser-ubuntu&hs=V3V&channel=fe&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=uQJfUe6GOqapiQLu64DoDw&ved=0CEAQsAQ&biw=1139&bih=808

Comment: Thanks, Will. So if we know the current compass bearing on a great circle flight path, and can keep track of our latitude, Clairaut gives us a simple way of calculating the compass bearing all along the path. Hmm. Could also be useful in a computer game, where we fly around the planet.

Comment: Do these last three types of geodesics close upon themselves, or do they never come to pass into their initial point in the proper manner for closure? If the latter, what can be said about their density- meaning, for example: is it true that in any neighborhood of a point on the torus, such a geodesic passes through that neighborhood?

Answer (score 6):

This question was posted a long time ago, but I will write my solution because I spent a lot of time stuck on this question.

$$\sigma(u,v) = ((r\cos(u)+a)\cos(v),(r \cos(u) + a )\sin(v), r \sin(u) ) $$

With $0<r<a$.

If $\gamma(t)= \sigma(u(t),v(t))$ is a geodesic parametrized by arc length, then $(u(t),v(t))$ must satisfy the differential equation (geodesic diffential equation)

$$v'' + 2\frac{(r\cos(u)+a)(r\cos(u)+a)' }{(r\cos(u)+a)^2} u' v' = 0 $$
$$u'' - \frac{(r\cos(u)+a) (r\cos(u)+a)'}{((r\cos(u)+a)')^2 + (\cos(u))^2} (v')^2 + \frac{r^2 \cos(u)\sin(u)}{((r\cos(u)+a)')^2 + (\cos(u))^2} (u')^2 = 0. $$

From the first equation, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}(r\cos(u(t)) +a)^2v'(t)) &= (r\cos(u)+a)^2 v''(t) + 2(r\cos(u(t)
 +a)(r\cos(u)+a)'  u' v'\\
&=(r\cos(u) + a)^2\left[ v'' + 2\frac{(r\cos(u)+a)(r\cos(u)+a)'}{(r\cos(u)+a)^2}u' v'\right] \\
&=0,
\end{align*}
which imply that $\exists$ $c \in \mathbb{R}$, such that

$$(r\cos(u(t) +a)^2 v'(t) = c.$$

Follows from these observations

\begin{align*}\cos(\theta(t)) &:= \frac{\langle \sigma_v(u(t),v(t)) , \gamma'(t)\rangle}{|\sigma_v(u(t),v(t))||\gamma'(t)|} \\
&= \frac{\langle \sigma_v , u'\sigma_u + v' \sigma_v \rangle}{\Vert\sigma_v\Vert}\\
 &= v' \Vert \sigma_v \Vert \\
&= v'(t)\cdot \Vert(-(r\cos(u(t))+a)\sin(v),(r \cos(u(t)) + a) \cos(v(t)) , 0)  \Vert\\
&=  (r \cos(u(t)) +a)v'(t) = \frac{c}{r\cos(u(t)) + a } 
\end{align*}

$$\Rightarrow (r \cos(u(t)) +a) \cos(\theta(t)) \equiv c. \qquad (1) $$

---

**a)$\gamma$ is tangent to the parallel $u=\pi/2$**

Suppose that $\exists$ $v_0,t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
\begin{align*}\gamma(t_0) &= \sigma\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, v_0\right)\right) \\
\gamma'(t_0) &= \pm \frac{\sigma_v \left(\frac{\pi}{2},v_0\right)}{\left|\sigma_v\left(\frac{\pi}{2},v_0\right)\right|},\mbox{ remember that }\gamma \mbox{ is parametrized by arc length}. 
\end{align*}

From (1)

$$c = (r \cos(u(t)) +a) \cos(\theta(t)) = (r \cos(u(t_0)) +a) \cos(\theta(t_0)) =  a \quad (2) .  $$

Supose by *reductio ad absurdum* that there is $t_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, satisfying $\gamma(t_1) = \sigma(u_1,v_1)$ with $u_1 \in [-\pi,\pi]\setminus [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Using (2)
$$(r \cos(u(t_1)) +a) \cos(\theta(t_1)) =  a, \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{note that $0\leq \cos(\theta(t))\leq 1$} $$
$$\Rightarrow  \cos(\theta(t_1)) =  \frac{a}{(r \cos(u(t_1)) +a)}, $$

which implies $\cos(\theta(t_1)) > 1$. Contradiction!!

These arguments prove the first part of your question .

---

**b) $\gamma$ intersect the parallel $u=0$ with angle $0<\theta<\pi/2$ .**

$\exists$ $t_0$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, such that

$$\gamma(t_0) = \sigma(0,v_0),\quad \cos(\theta(t_0))<\frac{a-r}{a+r} $$

From (1)

$$c = (r \cos(u(t)) +a) \cos(\theta(t)) = (r \cos(0) +a) \cos(\theta(t_0))  < a-r\qquad (3) $$

Suppose by *reductio ad absurdum* that $\gamma$  never reaches the parallel $u = \pi$, this is equivalent to say that $-\pi < u(t) < \pi$, $\forall$ $t$.

Note that $v'(t) \neq 0$, for all $t$. If $\exists$ $t_1$, such $v'(t_1) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\cos(\theta(t_1)) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\gamma'(t_1)$ is l.d. with a meridian, by the unicity of the geodesics (given a point and a direction there is a unique geodesic passing through this point) $\gamma$ must be the meridian, it implies that $\cos(\theta(t_0)) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\theta(t_0) = \theta = \pi/2$. Contradiction! So $v'(t) \neq 0$, $\forall$ $t$.

Suppose without loss of generality  that $v'(t) >0$ $\forall t$.

On the order hand $u'(t) \neq 0$. Suppose that $\exists$ $t_1$ such that $u'(t_1) = 0$, it implies that $\cos(\theta(t_1)) = 1$ (remember that we suppose that $-\pi < u(t)< \pi)$. But

$$c = (r\cos(u(t)) + a )\cos(\theta(t)) = (r \cos(u(t_1))+a) 1 > a-r $$

contradicts (3). So $u'(t) \neq 0$ $\forall$ $t$.

Suppose without loss of generality  that $u'(t) >0$ $\forall t$.

Note that by the hypothesis $\gamma$ is parametrized by arc length

$$ |u'| |\sigma_u| + |v'| |\sigma_v| = 1   $$

Using that

$$|\sigma_u| = r, \quad |\sigma_v| > a-r>0 $$

this implies that

$$0< u'(t) \leq 1/r , \qquad 0< v'(t) < 1/(r-a) \quad (4)$$

Now we can conclude that the domain of $\gamma$ contains $[t_0, \infty)$
. If this not occur exists a maximal $\omega^{+}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma: [0, \omega^+) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Remember that $(u(t),v(t))$ resolves the geodesic differential equation, by ODE theorems we know that $(u(t),v(t))$ $\to$ $\partial \mathbb{R}^2$ when $t \rightarrow \omega^{+}$ (This means that for every compact $K$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\exists$ $t_K$ such that  $(u(t),v(t)) \not\in K$, forall $t>t_K$).

so $$|(u(t),v(t))| \rightarrow \infty, \quad \mbox{when}\quad t \rightarrow \omega^{+}. $$

But from Mean Value Theorem and (4).

$$|u(t) - u(t_0)| < \frac{\omega^{+} - t_0}{r}  \quad |v(t) - v(t_0)| < \frac{\omega^{+}- t_0}{a-r}, \quad \forall t \in [t_0, \omega^{+})$$

Contradiction! Then $\gamma$ is well defined for all $t$ $\in$ $[t_0, \infty).$

Note that $u'(t) >0$, and (by the *reductio ad absurdum* hypothesis) $u(t) < \pi$, $\forall$ $t$ $\in$ $[t_0, \infty]$ as $u (t)$ is limited and increasing, there is $\tilde{u} \leq \pi$ satisfying
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(t) = \tilde{u} $$

Now we will prove that $\liminf\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} u'(t) \rightarrow 0 $ when $t \rightarrow \infty$. In case otherwise, there will be $ c> 0 $ such that $ u '(t)> c $ for all $ t> t_c $ which implies that
$$ | u (t) - u (t_c) | > c | t - t_c | $$
$$\Rightarrow u(t) \rightarrow \infty, \qquad \mbox{when} \quad t \rightarrow \infty $$
Contradiction! So $\exists$ sequence $(t_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that $t_k \rightarrow \infty$ and $u'(t_k) \rightarrow 0$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$. But this imply that

$$\cos(\theta (t_k)) \rightarrow 1, \quad \mbox{when}\quad k \rightarrow \infty $$
and
$$a-r > c = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (r\cos(u(t_k)) +a) \cos(\theta (t_k)) = (r \cos(\tilde{u}) +a ) 1 \geq a-r   $$
(Final) Contradiction! So we conclude that $u(t)$ must pass to $\pi$ (or $-\pi$, if you suppose that $u'(t) <0$).

Therefore, we proved the theorem.

Comment: Your solution for (a) is great. Your derivativion of $(1)$ also follows directly from Clairaut's relation. For (b) there is a much simpler solution:

Comment: $(r\cos(u)+a)\cos(\theta)=c \Rightarrow (r+a)\cos(\theta_0)=c \Rightarrow (a-r)\cos(\theta_T)=(r+a)\cos(\theta_0) \Rightarrow \cos(\theta_0)= \cos(\theta_T) \frac{(a-r)}{(a+r)} < \frac{(a-r)}{(a+r)}$ with strictness of the last inequality following from $(a)$.

Comment: @Dan At that time I demonstrate (1) without using directly Clairaut's relations just because I wanted a more elementary solution, but you are right, follows directly from Clairaut's relation. Your demonstration for (b) I didn't understand why your computation implies that the geodesic also intersects the parallel $u=π$? Can you explain, please?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your equations? I think the second one is not correct, but please correct me if I am wrong. The Christoffel symbols for the metric are $$\Gamma_{uv}^v = \Gamma_{vu}^v = \frac{r\sin u}{(a + r\cos u)},$$and $$\Gamma_{vv}^u = -\frac{r\sin u}{(a+r\cos u)}.$$This gives a differente second equation.